# Why does my IO.write insert a "%" sign at the end of output?

Tags: ruby, file, io

I use this line to read from temp.dat, which contains "100"

```
fahrenheit = IO.read("temp.dat").to_i * 9 / 5 + 32
```

Now, to write this result in another file;

Method 1

```
f = File.new("temp.out", "w")
f.puts fahrenheit
```

cat temp.out

```
212
```

Method 2

```
IO.write("temp.out", fahrenheit)
```

cat temp.out

```
212%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does my IO.write insert a “%” sign at the end of output?

It doesn't. Here's the binary content of the file. That `%` character is the command prompt of your shell, which is confused by the lack of EOL in the file. POSIX-compliant text files should always end lines with end-of-line character.

[image]